# CENTOS apache ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /path/to/shell.sh is not working

Tags: bash, apache, shell, centos, sudoers

I am trying to do a web interface by IPtables management.

I created a file, whose name is **test.php**

```
$output = shell_exec('bash /usr/bin/iptables.sh 2>&1');
echo $output;
```

I gave /usr/bin/iptables.sh NOPASSWD so I could execute the file with sudo through apache without using a password

```
sudo iptables -L
```

sudoers file :

```
apache ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/iptables.sh
```

But I am still getting the following error:

> We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
> Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things: #1)
> Respect the privacy of others. #2) Think before you type. #3) With
> great power comes great responsibility. sudo: a terminal is required
> to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard
> input or configure an askpass helper{"mode":"full","isActive":false}

However, if I use

```
apache ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Everything works fine.

I double-checked my directory and I used the exact path

```
[root@CentOS bin]# readlink -f iptables.sh
/usr/bin/iptables.sh
```

Super clueless here, can anyone help me with a direction? :'(

Comment: sudo configuration questions should go to linux management support sites.  SO is for programming questions.

Comment: I don't see see where your code is actually calling `sudo`. Your `shell_exec` command is calling `bash`, not `/usr/bin/iptables.sh`, so even if there's an explicit `sudo` there it's not going to match the configured path.

Comment: Often, `/etc/sudoers` is configured with the `requiretty` flag set (the set of default flags is earlier in the file, above what you quoted). Programs you run as a subprocess of a daemon typically don't have a controlling TTY. But sudoers configuration is off-topic here, and should be asked at [unix.se] instead.

Comment: BTW, note that `shell_exec()` is dangerous if you ever parameterize it to let the remote user configure anything. In general, it's much safer to use mechanisms to start an external executable that let you specify an explicit argument vector as an array, instead of a string that a shell is then started to _split out into_ an array (and potentially do other expansions/munging/etc as well).

Comment: Thank you for all your help ! This has been solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been solved.

The answer is here if someone has the same issue

https://serverfault.com/questions/1070602/centos-apache-all-root-nopasswd-path-to-shell-sh-is-not-working/

> bash is redundant

Just remove the bash and run  like this instead

```
$output = shell_exec('/usr/bin/iptables.sh 2>&1');
```